# Access azure key vault from azure blob storage (static website)

Tags: azure, web, azure-blob-storage, identity, azure-keyvault

I got a blob storage which I use as website.
This blob has a system assigned managed identity.

This identity is added to a key vault as access policy.
So actually it should be able to access the secrets.

But when I try it the way [microsoft documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/quick-create-node#code-example) it I got an error.

```
const getSecret = async () => {
        var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential({
            ManagedIdentityClientId: "<blob-id>",
        } as DefaultAzureCredentialOptions)
        const keyVaultName = "<key-vault-name>"
        const url = "https://" + keyVaultName + ".vault.azure.net"
        const client = new SecretClient(url, credential)
        const secret = await client.getSecret("function-key")
}
```

I got the error

```
Error: DefaultAzureCredential is not supported in the browser. Use InteractiveBrowserCredential instead.
    at Module.60308 (defaultAzureCredential.browser.js:5:34)
```

Is this even possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Please  check this [azure-sdk-for-js issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/issues/13407#issuecomment-780079748) according to which ,
  interactive credentials is [**recommended**](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/issues/12334#issuecomment-770335537) instead of default
  credentials.And for client side applications that run in the browser,
  the `InteractiveBrowserCredential` is the only credential type that is
  supported.Please check this [github reference](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/@azure/identity_2.0.4/sdk/identity/identity/samples/AzureIdentityExamples.md#:%7E:text=For%20Node.js%2C%20if%20a%20clientId%20is%20provided)
- So for interactive credentials for Node.js, if a clientId is
  provided, the Azure AD app  need to be configured to have a `"Mobile and desktop applications"` as `redirect` endpoint instead of web. See
  [set up redirect uri](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-desktop-app-registration#redirect-uris)

See [DefaultAzureCredential and examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/azure/identity-readme?view=azure-node-latest#:%7E:text=The%20DefaultAzureCredential%20is%20appropriate%20for%20most%20scenarios%20where,credentials%20used%20to%20authenticate%20in%20a%20development%20environment.)

Also according  to [DefaultAzureCredential Class | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.defaultazurecredential?view=azure-dotnet)
The following credential types if enabled will be tried, in order:

> EnvironmentCredential >ManagedIdentityCredential >
> SharedTokenCacheCredential > VisualStudioCredential >
> VisualStudioCodeCredential > AzureCliCredential>
> AzurePowerShellCredential >InteractiveBrowserCredential: `uses browser to auth users - not enabled by default. Pass true to the DefaultAzureCredential to enable it.`